# Python automation (pyautogui)

Tags: python, pyautogui

Does anyone know if it is possible for a pyautogui script to determine when a specific action is complete before proceeding to the next step?

I am busy with an automation project that opens an application and exports current reports. The problem that I am sitting with is that not all reports take the same time to export. This makes it difficult to decide how long the `pyautogui.PAUSE` needs to be.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Its been awhile since i used this but i think there is an image portion to this library. If there are visual ques you can use to determine the report is done you can search for those images until they are found then start the next report. https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I ended up using the locateOnScreen() in a while loop, so the loop will continue until the return value is not 'None'.

Answer (score 0):

use the following logic to force the program to complete clicks in sequence

```
image = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('image.png')
while image == None:
     image = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('image.png')
pyautogui.click(image)

image2 = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('image2.png')
while image2== None:
    image2 = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('image2.png')
pyautogui.click(image2)
```